# Which is a faster argument to pass: kbd, string, or vector?

Tags: key-bindings

When specifying a key sequence you have the option of using a kbd, string, or vector. Which one of these is faster? More efficient? Optimal in particular situations? Any trade-offs? Please list your reasoning and why.

Comment: Why do you care about the speed in this case? Do you have some indication that there is a speed difference or that the speed matters here? Other than the speed question, see @phils's answer: clarity for human readers. `kbd` is all about human readers.

Comment: Just curious is all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend using `kbd` in general, because of the way it eliminates any guess work in how to specify a key sequence. That benefit tends to outweighs everything else, IMO.

I actually thought that `kbd` was going to be 'slower' (by some entirely inconsequential margin) because it's not a macro, but a quick test to validate my assumptions shows that byte-compiled code actually contains the string or vector form, so apparently there is *no* speed benefit whatsoever to be had in avoiding `kbd`.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't know that. Great answer.

Comment: `kbd` is a "pure" function, so the byte compiler can substitute the result if you give a constant argument: `(get 'kbd 'pure) => t`

Comment: In fact, `kbd` was originally a Lisp macro (in `subr.el`).

Comment: I think the slowest aspect of using non-byte-compiled calls to `kbd` nowadays is the loading of its dependency `lisp/edmacro.el`.